# Factorial and exponential relationships (Problem)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, big-numbers

I have faced some problems like:

$x,A\in N$

$32!=A*10^x \Rightarrow Max(x)=?\\
26!=A*3^x \Rightarrow Max(x)=?$

My question will be stated after solving the first one as following:

Since $10=2*5$ and $Max(2,5)= 5$ then $32!$ is divisible by 5.

$32=6*5+2\\6=1*5+1\\1=0*5+1$

Hence $max(x)=6+1+0=7$

My question is How this process work? is there any other method to solve this problem? I am looking forwards to hear from you.

Best Regards.

Comment: Perhaps this? fun[base_, fac_] := Module[{x=0, f=fac}, While[Mod[f, base]==0, x=x+1; f=f/base]; ToString[f]<>"*"<>ToString[base]<>"^"<>ToString[x]]; Then fun[10,32!] displays 26313083693369353016721801216*10^7 and fun[3,26!] displays 6829776306569216000000*3^10. You can change what the function returns as needed. I chose to display as I did so that you could inspect the result. There are many other ways of doing this. Perhaps you can study this, understand how it works and how you might then do things like this for your next problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1808, Legendre showed that the exact power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is :

$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \rfloor$ where $k$ is the biggest power for $p$ that is less or equal to $n$ $p^k \leq n$ .

So  $k = \lfloor \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(p)} \rfloor$.

Now for the second example : $26! = A*3^x$ => $Max(x)=?$, since $3$ is prime number then we can find the biggest power that divide $26!$ and since $3^3 >26$ so the maximum power is $\lfloor \frac{26}{3} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{26}{3^2} \rfloor = 8+2 = 10$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have collected more information about Legendre method and it is really help me.